# MVC reCapcha Only Returns False

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, recaptcha

I am using:
http://mvcrecaptcha.codeplex.com/

My problem is very simple!

```
bool captchaValid
```

always returns false, no matter what I do.

Here is my code:

```
    [CaptchaValidator]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewWidget(int id, TagwallViewModel model, bool captchaValid)
    {
        model.TagwallCollection = new TagWallCollection() { Id = id };


        if (!captchaValid)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "You did not type the verification word correctly. Please try again.");
        }
        else
```

It shows no errors..

Things i have done differently, but i think have no influence:

The cs files downloaded from codeplex is not in the same folders.

**I registered on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create to get my two keys with a online domain, but i'm testing it on localhost.**
That was my problem, sorry for troubleing you! Having a bad code day.

I am using Razor.

Comment: Well, what have you done and what is your question?

Comment: I have added Recaptcha.dll to my refrences and followed the steps shown in the link. I'll but on some of my code.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question.

Comment: I suppose he wants to know why it always return false, and how to make it return true if the captcha is valid

Comment: Sorry :/ captchaValid is suppost to return true, if you type in the correct letters, however it returns false no matter what. What could be the problem?, i it's not the most specific question i know.. But it's what i've got.

Comment: Rather than edit your question it is better to answer and mark as correct. Especially given that no answer has been given at this point. It marks the question as answered more obviously.

Comment: I have the same problem. i'm testing my soulution on localhost and validation is always false. 
Will my solution work out of localhost?